# Cast Variable to Output of "typeof" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, casting, typeof

I'm making a system in JavaScript where I can set and get variables from local storage. My problem is when I set a variable which is an integer to local storage and I get it back from local storage it returns a string not an integer/number.

I have tried typeof in JavaScript and I don't know how to cast my variable from local storage (string) to the variable (integer).

```
function setVar(name, value) {
    // Set variable type
    var json = localStorage.getItem("types");
    if(json == null) {
        json = {};
    }else{
        json = JSON.parse(json);
    }
    json[name] = typeof value;
    localStorage.setItem("types", JSON.stringify(json));
    // Set the variable
    localStorage.setItem(name, value);
}

function getVar(name, defaultValue = 0) {
    var v = localStorage.getItem(name);
    // Set default value if value is not already set
    if(v == null) {
        setVar(name, defaultValue);
        v = defaultValue;
    }
    // Cast to value type
    var type = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("types"))[name];

    // TODO: Cast v (string from localStorage) to type (output from typeof) 

    return v;
}
```

Everything works I just need to figure out how to cast my variable to the desired type. I might be approaching this the wrong way but anything helps.

Comment: Just use `localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(value));` and the `JSON.parse` the value from the string you get back. No need to store the type in a separate object (for that you use JSON anyway).

Comment: @Bergi is correct. Just `stringify` when inserting it into local storage, and the `parse` when you pull it out. But keep in mind that `JSON.stringify` can't parse all data types properly. ES6 data structures can't be properly stringified with its default behavior. You'll have to get a little creative if you want to store `Set`s and `Map`s

Comment: @Bergi Yes, that is what I want exactly it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try using if-else like this

```
if(type == 'number') { v = parseFloat(v) }
else if(type == 'string') { v = v.toString() } // Just an example
```

Comment: `v` is already a string, there's no need to call `.toString()`.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about doing something like that but I don't want to do that for all of the outcomes of the typeof output. Do you think there is a more efficient way of doing that? Meaning, you don't have to specify if the type equals to a number or boolean, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution thanks to @Bergi

```
function setVar(name, value) {
    // Set the variable
    localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(value));
}

function getVar(name, defaultValue = 0) {
    // Get variable from local storage
    var v = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(name));
    // Set default value if value is not already set
    if(v == null) {
        setVar(name, defaultValue);
        v = defaultValue;
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: `JSON.parse` Will Šitner be primitivně (string, number), object, null, undefined, or will throw if value stored is not parseable